# Display last 10 rows in mysql with a running balance column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The code below which I used to compute for the running balance of a bank account table works fine. I got the running balance as expected.

```
SELECT
    `balance1`.`ID`, 
    `balance1`.`Date`, 
    `balance1`.`Credit`, 
    `balance1`.`Debit`, 
    @Balance := @Balance + `balance1`.`Credit` - `balance1`.`Debit` AS `Balance`,
        `balance1`.`Remarks`
FROM `balance1`, (SELECT @Balance := 0) AS variableInit 
ORDER BY `balance1`.`ID` ASC
```

However, what if I want to display the last 10 items of the table. To first sort the table  in descending order with a limit of 10, then to sort in ascending order again will not work because the Balance column, which is a computed column, will be affected.

Is there any way to display the last 10 rows without affecting the computation in the Balance column?

Answer (score 1):

How about using your existing query as a sub query to get the top 10 `balance1.ID` sorted in descending order.  Then in the outer query sort  `balance1.ID` in ascending order:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT b.ID, b.Date, b.Credit, b.Debit, b.Remarks,
         @Balance := @Balance + b.Credit - b.Debit AS Balance
  FROM balance1 b, (SELECT @Balance := 0) AS variableInit 
  ORDER BY b.ID DESC
  LIMIT 10
) m
ORDER BY m.ID ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
ORDER BY `balance1`.`ID` ASC
```

use

```
ORDER BY `balance1`.`ID` DESC LIMIT 10
```